# User's style for vanilla JS webcomponent

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

I have this component:

index.html

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="clock.js"></script>
    <style>
        clock-digital div {
            background-color: green;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <clock-digital></clock-digital>
</body>

</html>
```

clock.js

```js
customElements.define('clock-digital', class extends HTMLElement {

    constructor() {
        super();
        var shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({
            mode: 'open'
        });
        this._clockID = setInterval(function () {
            var currentdate = new Date();
            var hours = ( (currentdate.getHours() < 10) ? '0' : '') + currentdate.getHours();
            var minutes = ( (currentdate.getMinutes() < 10) ? '0' : '') + currentdate.getMinutes();
            var seconds = ( (currentdate.getSeconds() < 10) ? '0' : '') + currentdate.getSeconds();
            shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
            <style>
                div {
                    display: inline-block;
                    width: 65px;
                    text-align: center;
                    background-color: whitesmoke;
                    font-style: italic;
                    border: 1px solid lightgray;
                    border-radius: 3px;
                    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px;
                }
            </style>
            <div>
                ${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}
            </div>`;
        }, 500);
    }

});
```

I want that user of component can define his style on clock. I tried with:

```html
<style>
        clock-digital div {
            background-color: green;
        }
    </style>
```

but it doesn't work. Should I use the slot tag somewhere in shadow root? What is best practice to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could expose [CSS properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables/#defining-variables) in your custom element that could be set externally.

In your example, your element could define `--clock-background-color`, which sets the `div`'s background color:

```
shadowRoot.innerHTML = 
  `<style>
     div {
       background-color: var(--clock-background-color, whitesmoke);
       /* ... */
     }
   </style>
   <div>
     ${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}
   </div>`;
```

Then, your element's users could change the background color to green with this:

```
<style>
  clock-digital {
    --clock-background-color: green;
  }
</style>
<clock-digital></clock-digital>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/QdWqKq?editors=1010)

<sup>Note the Codepen demo uses Web Components polyfills for non-Chrome browsers, but you can comment it out to see that it still works vanilla in Chrome.</sup>

Comment: That's a very elegant solution, I don't know about custom CSS properties. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can also take profit of the priority of the user defined CSS rules over the **:host** selector that represents the Shadow DOM root (i.e. the custom element itself).

In your custom element, use `:host` to style the content:

```
shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
    <style>
        :host {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 65px;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: whitesmoke;
            font-style: italic;
            border: 1px solid lightgray;
            border-radius: 3px;
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px;
        }
    </style>
    <div>
        ${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}
    </div>`
```

Now the user can define its own styles with standard CSS notation, like for any HTML elements. This will override the styles defined by the `:host` rule.

```
<style>
     clock-digital {
         background-color: green;
         color: white;
     }
</style>
```

```js
customElements.define('clock-digital', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        var shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
        this._clockID = setInterval(function () {
            var currentdate = new Date();
            var hours = ('0'+currentdate.getHours()).substr(-2,2)
            var minutes = ('0'+currentdate.getMinutes()).substr(-2,2)
            var seconds = ('0'+currentdate.getSeconds()).substr(-2,2) 
            shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
            <style>
                :host {
                    display: inline-block;
                    width: 65px;
                    text-align: center;
                    background-color: whitesmoke;
                    font-style: italic;
                    border: 1px solid lightgray;
                    border-radius: 3px;
                    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px;
                }
            </style>           
            ${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

```css
clock-digital  {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<clock-digital></clock-digital>
```

Comment: Ok that's also good. There is a best practice? :host or custom properties css? If I want user can access not only for root of shadow but also for some part of children of the root, how can I achieve that?

Comment: There's no best practice, only adapted solutions :-) I would say :host is better for simple custom element (like in your question) and custom properties can address more complex cases (like in your comment). You could also use other solutions like attributes or style import. It depends also on targeted platform (Edge doesn't support custom properties yet).

Comment: Note that if you want to let users style all the content of your custom element, you could use normal DOM instead of Shadow DOM. It's also valid "vanilla" Web Components.

Comment: Yes, but in that case my style can change the style of other user's tags, I don't have anymore the scope property of shadow DOM. if I don't wrong.

Comment: Not if all your style rules starts with the name of the custom element.

Comment: Right and if I use link with import html (hence not using template string) I can put style out of template tag and so the style won't be repeated in the DOM.

Comment: Is there an hybrid solution?
Component like this:

component.html

<style>
tag-name {
     .....
}
</style>
<template>
        ..........
</template>
<script>
   ........ clone template and attach in shadowRoot
</script>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132299/discussion-between-supersharp-and-asv).